proxy chain in golang
i want to setup a http proxy that proxy request to another http proxy that has authenticate.
this proxy server will be used with selenium for chrome webdriver proxy because it dosent support authenticated http proxy right away.

type ProxyChain struct {
    Server *http.Server
}

func NewProxyChain(remoteProxyUrl string, localProxyAddr string) (*ProxyChain, error) {

    log.Printf("New ProxyChain from %s to %s", localProxyAddr, remoteProxyUrl)

    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(remoteProxyUrl)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Join(errors.New("parsing remote proxy url Failed"), err)
    }

    proxyFunc := http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)
    transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: proxyFunc}
    handler := makeHandler(transport)

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    localProxyAddr,
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(handler),
    }

    return &ProxyChain{
        Server: server,
    }, nil
}


above code create a transport for given proxy url. when i create a client with that transport and sent some get request it return status code 200. but then when i create a http server, handler cannot successfuly accept and transfer http proxy request to that server:
func makeHandler(t *http.Transport) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        if r.Method != http.MethodConnect {
            http.Error(w, "This server only support connect request", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            log.Print("This server only support connect request!")
            return
        }

        r.URL.Scheme = "http"
        r.RequestURI = ""

        client := &http.Client{Transport: t}

        
        resp, err := client.Do(r)
        
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            http.Error(w, "Error sending proxy request", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        // Copy the headers from the proxy response to the original response
        for name, values := range resp.Header {
            for _, value := range values {
                w.Header().Add(name, value)
            }
        }

        // log.Printf("Status Code: %d", resp.StatusCode)
        log.Printf("Status: %s", resp.Status)

        // Set the status code of the original response to the status code of the proxy response
        w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)

        // Copy the body of the proxy response to the original response
        _, err = io.Copy(w, resp.Body)

        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            return
        }
    }
}

with above code i get connection reset by peer and other network errors.
how can i fix handler function or is there a package that do proxy chaining for me? thanks for helping.
